# How do I use the rabbitmq in my .net core web

Tags: web, rabbitmq

As the title suggests,Examples on the official website are console project but is it really impossible to apply to asp.net core web?
My web project as a consumer or producer but does not output received information,But the rabbitmq page console displays the queue messages sent,so What are consumers or producer in the actual production environment?windows server?console? 
this is my api code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult sendMgs()
        {
            string message = string.Empty;
            //var uri = new Uri("amqp://192.168.150.129:5672");
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                UserName = "admin",
                Password = "admin",
                Port=5672,
                HostName= "192.168.150.129",
                RequestedHeartbeat = 0,
                VirtualHost= "/vhost_mmr"
                //Endpoint = new AmqpTcpEndpoint(uri)
            };

            using (var connection=factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue:"hello",
                                         durable:false,
                                         exclusive:false,
                                         autoDelete:false,
                                         arguments:null);
                    message = "Hello World";
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                         routingKey:"hello",
                                         basicProperties:null,
                                         body:body);

                }
            }
            return Json(new {message = message });
        }
```

and this my mvc web code:

```
public IActionResult MqTest()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("test begin:");
            GetQueueMsg();
            return View();
        }
 public void GetQueueMsg()
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                UserName = "admin",
                Password = "admin",
                Port = 5672,
                HostName = "192.168.150.129",
                RequestedHeartbeat = 0,
                VirtualHost = "/vhost_mmr"
            };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel =connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                     consumer.Received +=  (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body;
                        var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        ViewBag.msg = msg;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("test：" + msg);
                    };

                    var ret = channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                                         autoAck: true,
                                         consumer: consumer);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just plug `RabbitMQ.Client` package to your project and you good to go. There is no any limitation on project type.

Comment: I tried use web api as a producer use mvc web as a consumer,but In the end, I failed,if i use console as producer and consumer,it's success.Like the official website example,So I think the type of project has an impact

Comment: no, it doesn't... what do you mean *you failed*? In which way? Consumer didn't receive the message? I wouldn't put consumer (listener) as a web application for architectural reasons; and if you do, rabbitmq is running on a different port from web app. But it doesn't mean that it is failing!

Comment: @Felix  but if I changed the consumer into a console system, and I still use web API as a producer Consumers still can't receive the message. Unless the console is used as the producer, As for Windows service, I haven't used it before, so it's not clear.